# Find a Text and scroll into it with javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, find

I have a div that contains hundreds of lines.
I want to create a function that allows me to find a text and scroll into it:

```
function findAndScroll(text)
```

So, I enter the wanted text in an input text, I click on the "Go" button that will trigger the "findAndScroll" function then I get scrolled to that text.

Before coding, is there an existant jQuery plugin or a javascript library
that can do this?

Thank you,

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a function like [this](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/find-and-replace-text-with-javascript/) to find the text and highlight it. You can then scroll to the highlighted element like this:

```
var offset = $("#id_of_highlighted_element").offset().top;
window.scrollTo(0,offset);
```

or you can simply go the id like this

```
window.location = "#id_of_highlighted_element";
```

However `window.scrollTo` is more flexible because you can set the element to wherever you want on the page.